# How to enable kerberos authentication to a Java web app

Tags: linux, authentication, java, kerberos

I'm currently using Centrify to aid with Kerberos/AD integration in our environment. Right now we have Kerberos enabled on a Centrified version of Apache. We are trying to run jnlp files through javaws and are having problems with passing Kerberos credentials along.

I have enabled Kerberos in the about:config section of Firefox and am able to pass authentication to apache, but get stopped at an "Authentication Required" screen from Java saying "Enter you login details to access  on ." This same Window also says "Authentication Scheme: Integrated Windows"

How can I ensure these Kerberos credentials are passed to Java? At this point I don't even think Java is listening for Kerberos, so maybe the key is enabling this feature, however, I'm not sure how to go about doing this.

I'm running jdk-1.7.0_u51 and trying to connect to Apache from a Fedora 19 desktop.

Comment: did you create SPN  ? you can use fiddler to be sure negotiate is proposed and answered by firefox. Try with internet explorer before firefox. Also check time and date, must be in sync (<5mn drift)

Comment: Can't try with IE as we are connecting to Apache from a Linux machine. Also I don't know what creating a SPN means. Looking into that now.

Comment: if you don't know what is a Service Principal Name (SPN), then your kerberos setup can't be good. Kerberos is based on SPN